# Write the Fourier integral of x^2

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, dirac-delta

I was asked to write down the Fourier integral of $x^2$ using the following convention:

$$\begin{align*}
\text{Fourier transform}\quad&\hat{f}(k) = \dfrac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,e^{-ikx}\,\mathrm dx \\
\text{Fourier integral}\quad&f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(k)\,e^{ikx}\,\mathrm dk
\end{align*}$$

However the solution has baffled me as it was written as follows:
$$
x^2 = -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta''(k)\,e^{ikx}\,\mathrm dk
$$

I have no idea how this is the solution any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you not sure why that integral is equal to $x^2$?

Comment: yes i have never come across that before

Comment: Have you seen the Fourier transform in the sense of distributions, and do you know anything about the Dirac delta?

Comment: What did you come up with when you did it? Integration by parts twice?

Comment: Note the $x^2$ is not an L^2 function so the question certainly means in a distributional sense

Comment: i know about the dirac delta function yes

Comment: The Riesz representation theorem fails for $V = C^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{R})$, and there are some maps $f\in V^*$ not given by $f(\phi) = \langle \phi_0, \phi\rangle = \int \phi_0 \phi$ for some fixed $\phi_0$. The functional $f \to f^{n}(0)$ is one of those maps, and it's denoted by $\delta^{(n)}$; that is, $\int \delta^{(n)} f = f^{(n)}(0)$. The notation is suggested by integration by parts, although of course the $\delta^{(n)}$ are not actually functions.